# How in T-SQL to multiplying two different datatypes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I multiply two types in SQL Server?

I have one column with cost, whose datatype is `money`, and another `integer` column that has the number of those products.

How can I multiply these two values to result in a value representing the cost?

Example: `$2000 * 2`

Comment: Have you tried it ? And what is your problem ?

Comment: I hope the OP doesn't store the "money" as a string `$2000`, like in the example

Comment: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) read the `Implicit Conversions` section

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
SELECT t.number_of_items * t.cost_of_item AS total_cost
  FROM PRODUCTS t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @UNITS int
DECLARE @UnitCost money

SET @UNITS = 100
SET @UnitCost = 2.20

SELECT (@UNITS * CONVERT(decimal(18,2), @unitcost)) as Total

Replace the @variables with your column names.
```

Comment: you don't need the `CONVERT`, this work the same: `SELECT @UNITS * @unitcost as Total`

Comment: Realized that after I wrote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Dependantly of the types **implicit** or **explicit convertion** will take place (as @KM commented).

Implicit convertion is done automatically by SQL Server (which is your case). If it is not possible *Error* occurs.

Explicit convertion is done by developer (in SQL server using `CAST` or `CONVERT`). If convertion is not possible *Error* occurs.

For more information see SQL Server [CAST and CONVERT help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).